# create a dynamic view in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a sql to calculate wip data.

```
select 'WIP Balance - sls' item,area ima12,sum(aug) amt,'201808' dat from frdata.careawipsts@mesrpt where area != 'WH' group by area
union all
select 'WIP Balance - sls' item,'Subtotal WIP balance' ima12,sum(amt),'201808' dat from
(select 'WIP Balance - sls' item,area ima12,sum(aug) amt,'201808' dat from frdata.careawipsts@mesrpt where area != 'WH' group by area)
union all

select 'WIP Balance - sls' item,area ima12,sum(wip) amt,'201809' dat from frdata.careawipsts@mesrpt where area != 'WH' group by area
union all
select 'WIP Balance - sls' item,'Subtotal WIP balance' ima12,sum(amt),'201809' dat from
(select 'WIP Balance - sls' item,area ima12,sum(sep) amt,'201809' dat from frdata.careawipsts@mesrpt where area != 'WH' group by area)
```

Every month the table carewipsts in dblink mesrpt will add a column include last month value with name like aug,sep,oct like etc. And I use the sql to caluclate amount and total for each month group by area. Now I have to manually update the SQL every month. Is it possible to do it automatically? If not, if the table in dblink with fixed column for whole year. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should try materialized view. Something like this:

```
Create Materialized view temp_mv
refresh complete start with (sysdate) next (TRUNC(add_months(SYSDATE,1),'MM'))
as select ...
```